# Navigator.pop does not closing showModalBottomSheet when the StartWidget is displayed again

Tags: flutter

I have the following route:
StartWidget -> showModalBottomSheet -> NextWidget -> NextWidget: Doing some work and calls finally Navigator.pop and showing MainWidget but with open showModalBottomSheet.

Which navigator method do i have to use, in order to display only the StartWidget?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: How can i share a reduced version of my code here in a comment?

Comment: I gonna asked the question new with more, this question can be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.pushNamed returns a Future. As such, perhaps if you just add the await like so

```
void goToNextPage() async {
<...do something 1...>
await Navigator.pushNamed(context, screenName);
<...do something 2...> //open bottom sheet
}
```

It can solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry for late response i gonna try it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you can use the popUntil method to get back to the StartWidget, the documentation is here:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html

Comment: I think it is not what the author meant, though he didn't provide enough information to be sure.